# Why does over-sampling mess up arrows?

Tags: tikz-pgf, arrows

I have two images below. One is with a sampling of 200 and another without any As you can see, the first image has a beautiful arrow whereas in the second image, the line has gone beyond the actual arrow-head, resulting in a strange arrow-tip. This uses the `LaTeX` arrow-head, with some modifications to the width and height to make it larger.

**Bad version with oversampling:**

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,shapes,angles, decorations.pathmorphing}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[line width=0.5pt, -{Latex[length=6pt,width=4pt]}] (-3.5,0)--(3.5,0)node[above, xshift=-0.12cm]{$x$};
\draw[line width=0.5pt, -{Latex[length=6pt,width=4pt]}] (0,-3.5)--(0,3.5)node[right, yshift=-0.15cm]{$y$};

\draw[xscale=1, yscale=1, line width=1pt, domain=-3.5:-0.6,
smooth,variable=\x, bluegraph ,latex-latex,samples=200] plot ({\x},{(-2/\x)});
\draw[xscale=1, yscale=1, line width=1pt, domain=0.6:3.5,
smooth,variable=\x, bluegraph ,latex-latex,samples=200] plot ({\x},{(-2/\x)});

\foreach \x/\y in {-1/2} {
    \fill (\x,\y) circle (3pt);
    \node[above left] at (\x,\y) {$(\x,\y)$};
}
\end{tikzpicture} 
\end{document}
```

**Good version without sampling:**

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,shapes,angles, decorations.pathmorphing}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[line width=0.5pt, -{Latex[length=6pt,width=4pt]}] (-3.5,0)--(3.5,0)node[above, xshift=-0.12cm]{$x$};
\draw[line width=0.5pt, -{Latex[length=6pt,width=4pt]}] (0,-3.5)--(0,3.5)node[right, yshift=-0.15cm]{$y$};

\draw[xscale=1, yscale=1, line width=1pt, domain=-3.5:-0.6,
smooth,variable=\x, bluegraph ,latex-latex] plot ({\x},{(-2/\x)});
\draw[xscale=1, yscale=1, line width=1pt, domain=0.6:3.5,
smooth,variable=\x, bluegraph ,latex-latex] plot ({\x},{(-2/\x)});

\foreach \x/\y in {-1/2} {
    \fill (\x,\y) circle (3pt);
    \node[above left] at (\x,\y) {$(\x,\y)$};
}
\end{tikzpicture} 
\end{document}
```

1. Why does increasing the sampling result in this occurring?
2. What can I do to prevent this happening, without manually experimenting to find the perfect balance between sampling accuracy and arrow-tip aesthetics?

[image]
[image]

Comment: Try using a newer version of TokZ.  (one that uses arrows.meta instead of arrows).

Comment: Your code examples are not compilable.