# PGF Plot Sampling Messes up Arrows

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-arrows

When creating some plots with pgf, sampling messes up arrow tips of some functions such as the square root function. I increase the sampling to 100 to make the function look better but the arrow at the end gets messed up. This topic has been brought up before [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/455357/why-does-over-sampling-mess-up-arrows) but I cannot find an answer to resolve this issue.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta ,shapes,angles, decorations.pathmorphing}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[line width=0.5pt, -{Latex[length=6pt,width=4pt]}] (-3.5,0)--(3.5,0)node[above, xshift=-0.12cm]{$x$};
\draw[line width=0.5pt, -{Latex[length=6pt,width=4pt]}] (0,-3.5)--(0,3.5)node[right, yshift=-0.15cm]{$y$};

\draw[xscale=1, yscale=1, line width=1pt, domain=-3.5:-0.6,
smooth,variable=\x,latex-latex,samples=200] plot ({\x},{(-2/\x)});
\draw[xscale=1, yscale=1, line width=1pt, domain=0.6:3.5,
smooth,variable=\x,latex-latex,samples=200] plot ({\x},{(-2/\x)});

\foreach \x/\y in {-1/2} {
    \fill (\x,\y) circle (3pt);
    \node[above left] at (\x,\y) {$(\x,\y)$};
}
\end{tikzpicture} 
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: It's going to be difficult to suggest corrections to a code you don't show... Please read about [Minimal Working Example](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-working-example-mwe-what-is-that) and edit your question accordingly. Thank you.

Comment: @Miyase I've now included and example.

Comment: Quick fix: `shorten >=-2pt, shorten <=-2pt`.

Comment: @Jasper Habicht Thanks, this works; I hope there is a more standard way this can be dealt with.

Answer (score 3):

This is not possible to do without cheating. The `plot` draws many small line segments (or many small curves with the `smooth` option). When an arrow tip is applied, the curve is shortened to not show the curve under the tip. A shortening is only applied to the first(or last) line segment(or curve), so when it is too short it fails.

From the manual about arrows page 192:

> TikZ will modify the path by shortening the first segment and
> shortening a segment below its length may result in strange effects.

---

The cheating solution could be to cover the line with something white (if the background is not white or monochromatic, the solution gets a bit more complicated) and then draw the arrow afterwards like this:

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=1cm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[ultra thick, {Circle[white]}-{Circle[white]}, postaction={Latex-Latex, tips}] plot[domain=0.6:3.5, samples=200] ({\x},{(-2/\x)});
\end{tikzpicture} 
\end{document}
```

[image: Curve with arrowtips]

---

A color version, to show what is happening

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=1cm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[ultra thick, {Circle[blue]}-{Circle[blue]}, postaction={{Latex[teal]}-{Latex[teal]}, tips}] plot [domain=0.6:3.5, samples=200] ({\x},{(-2/\x)});
\draw[red] plot[domain=0.6:3.5, samples=200] ({\x},{(-2/\x)});
\end{tikzpicture} 
\end{document}
```

[image: Curve with circle and pointy arrow tips]

Comment: @JasperHabicht: With your negative shortening, you make the first and last segment long enough that it is no longer a problem for the arrow to do its shortening. With this solution, the arrowhead ends up in the wrong place.

Comment: Thank you for the in-depth explanation. I appreciate the knowledge you have shared.