# Add reversed arc barb tip at the end of a curve

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-arrows, arrow-curve

I'd like to add a reversed arc barb tip to a curve in order to mark a discontinuity. While this works perfectly fine at the end of a line (and not a curve), reverting the barb tip horizontally at the end of a curve causes the curve to slightly cross the hook, as shown below:

[image]

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[black] [domain=0:2,-{Arc Barb[reversed]}, samples=100] plot (\x,0); % the curve crosses the hook
\draw[-{Arc Barb[reversed]}] (0,-1) -- (2,-1); % well-functioning plot I cannot generalise for curves
    \end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Could you please help me clip the end of the curve in the first example, or make the arrow tip begin a bit further?

Comment: Can you show your real plot? I suspect that if a sample lies between the start of the arrow tip and the actual end of the line, PGF messes up somewhere. Compare with `\draw[-{Arc Barb[reversed]}] (0,-1) -- (1.99,-1) -- (2,-1);`.

Comment: See also https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/652578/8650

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of shortening the curve, you can move the arrowhead to the end.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[black, shorten >=-2pt] [domain=0:2,-{Arc Barb[reversed]}, samples=100] plot (\x,0); % the curve crosses the hook
\draw[-{Arc Barb[reversed]}] (0,-1) -- (2,-1); % well-functioning plot I cannot generalise for curves
    \end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image: demo]

Comment: Thank you, that's what I needed!

Comment: If you want the arrowhead in the original position, which is needed for non tirvial plots, then you can use the method here: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/652578/8650